# Initializing a member of an argument to javascript function with server side variable

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

Developing in ASP.NET using VB.NET as code behind (I don't do this for a living :-) )

In an attempt to dynamically display all the contents of myDir, I replaced the following code that worked well by displaying a slide show in the specified div (culled for brevity):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var mygallery1=new fadeSlideShow
    ({
        wrapperid: "divIDBelow"
        ...
        imagearray: [
            ["./myDir/image1.jpg", "", ""],
            ["./myDir/image2.jpg", "", ""]
            ],
        displaymode: ...
            ...
    })    
</script>
```

with:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var mygallery1=new fadeSlideShow
    (
    {
        wrapperid: "divIDBelow"
        ...
        imagearray: '<%=fileList.ToString() %>',
        displaymode: ...
            ...
    }
    )
    var imagearr = '<%=fileList.ToString() %>'; //for debugging purposes

    alert(imagearr); // for debugging purposes
</script>
```

where fileList is a server side public StringBuilder variable that is initialized with the contents of "myDir".

The debugging alert outputs the following:

```
[["./myDir/image1.jpg", "", ""],
 ["./myDir/image2.jpg", "", ""]]
```

But the imagearray member in the fadeslideshow function call's variable does not seem to initialize properly as the slide show presents just a white image (as opposed to the results in the hardcoded path version).

Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

imagearray is coming as string not an array, so create new array and fill it up with correct elements and pass it to imagearray.